# Merge 2 docx with different header and footer

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I have 2 (and more) docx with différent header and footer and I want to merge them keeping the different header and footer. I use POI and I have that code which merge the 2 docx, the problem is that the second part of the final file (so the 2 docx to merge) doesn't have any header and footer.

```
public static void merge(InputStream src1, InputStream src2, OutputStream dest) throws Exception {
    OPCPackage src1Package = OPCPackage.open(src1);
    OPCPackage src2Package = OPCPackage.open(src2);
    XWPFDocument src1Document = new XWPFDocument(src1Package);        
    CTBody src1Body = src1Document.getDocument().getBody();
    XWPFDocument src2Document = new XWPFDocument(src2Package);
    CTBody src2Body = src2Document.getDocument().getBody();        
    appendBody(src1Body, src2Body);
    src1Document.write(dest);
}

private static void appendBody(CTBody src, CTBody append) throws Exception {
    XmlOptions optionsOuter = new XmlOptions();
    optionsOuter.setSaveOuter();
    String appendString = append.xmlText(optionsOuter);
    String srcString = src.xmlText();
    String prefix = srcString.substring(0,srcString.indexOf(">")+1);
    String mainPart = srcString.substring(srcString.indexOf(">")+1,srcString.lastIndexOf("<"));
    String sufix = srcString.substring( srcString.lastIndexOf("<") );
    String addPart = appendString.substring(appendString.indexOf(">") + 1, appendString.lastIndexOf("<"));
    CTBody makeBody = CTBody.Factory.parse(prefix+mainPart+addPart+sufix);
    src.set(makeBody);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two word documents which are saved with .docx to a third file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008540/how-to-merge-two-word-documents-which-are-saved-with-docx-to-a-third-file)

Comment: The solution in that question doesn't solve my problem

Comment: It seems that you are using internal method `getDocument(...)` in your code. Your method `appendBody(...)` heavily relies on String processing. It totally bypasses the way POI expects you to process the document elements like `java.util.List<XWPFHeader>`. The solution I have cited earlier DOES show how to process `java.util.List<IBodyElement>`. You can extend that approach to process `java.util.List<XWPFHeader>`.

Comment: Ok, I try to adapt the solution in the link but I have a first problem. If a file contains picture, they don't appear in the final file, there is just a blank frame with a message which say that word can't load the picture

Comment: Take a look at [XWPFDocument](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html) fields. You will have to process all the fields if your merge is to completely process the documents.

Comment: In order to manage differing headers and footers, you are going to have to implement sections. Section info is stored in a different place for the default section vs. other sections. If you have a couple documents with a single section, and you want to retain all that section info, you are going to have to convert all but the last document's section info from the default section to an additional section.